# JQTouch & PHP constantly updating data

Tags: php, iphone, ajax, jqtouch

I have been working on a very basic app in jqTouch and have run into a problem, any help is appreciated. My application works as follows,

I have a textfile on my webserver that has new values truncated to it constantly. There will only ever be two numerical values separated by a colon in the text file. I.e "0:2.5"

How can I essentially grab whatever 2 values are in this text file every 10 seconds and echo them in jQtouch? At the moment, I'm using fread to read the file and then echo the result in a div. This works...however I'm lost as how to make it fread every 10 seconds then echo the new value every 10 seconds?

Any help is so appreciated, thanks alot. What little code I have, is below.

```
<?php
$myFile = "VoltageData.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 6);
fclose($fh);
?>
<div id="get">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>GET Example</h1>
    <a class="back" href="#">AJAX</a>
</div>
<div class="info">
    This page was loaded via AJAX.
</div>
<ul class="rounded">
    <li><a href="#livetest"><?php echo $theData; ?></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="livetest">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Events test</h1>
    <a class="back" href="#">AJAX</a>
    <a class="button goback" href="#home">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="info">
    This is a test of live events.
</div>
</div>'
```